# MySQL group_concat and concat surname, lastname and title

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**places**

> ```
> id | name   | year |
> --------------------
> 1  | Berlin | 1966 |
> 2  | Paris  | 2012 |
> ```

and

**member**

> ```
> id | title | surname | lastname | idPlace |
> -------------------------------------------
> 1  | Dr    | Maxi    | Bax      | 1       |
> 2  |       | Ameli   | Steifer  | 2       |
> 3  |       | Wonder  | Woman    | 1       |
> 4  |       | Harry   | Barry    | 2       |
> ```

As a result I would like to get

> ```
> name    | year | members                     |
> ----------------------------------------------
> Berlin  | 2011 | Dr Maxi Bax, Wonder Woamn   |
> Parins  | 2050 | Ameli Steifer, Harry Barry  |
> ```

I managed to get with this SQL

```
SELECT p.name, p.year, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(m.title, " " ,m.surname," ", m.lastname) SEPARATOR ', ') 
AS members FROM places p INNER JOIN member m on p.id = m.idPlace 
GROUP BY m.idPlace
```

the following result

> ```
> name    | year | members                     |
> ----------------------------------------------
> Berlin  | 2011 | Dr Maxi Bax,  Wonder Woamn   |
> Parins  | 2050 | Ameli Steifer,  Harry Barry  |
> ```

which produces an extra whitespace before *Wonder Woman* and *Harry Barry*. Is it possible to get the result without the extra whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the space in your CONCAT function. Both `Wonder Woamn` and `Harry Barry` do not have a title, therefore the CONCAT function method returns `[emtpy-string][space]Wonder[space][Woamn]`. When you combine this with your GROUP_CONCAT, which has a trailing space, it appears as two spaces.

One solution to this problem is to return the space with the title, if and only if the title is not null.

`CONCAT(IF(m.title IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT(m.title, " ")))`

A similar issue can exist with your other columns as well. You could, alternatively, run a REGEXP search/replace to replace any extra spaces, but that's a whole another scenario and I would advise against it.